# How can I specify Preprocessor directive from Eclipse CDT?

Tags: c++, eclipse

I would like to specify to the GCC C++ Compiler the following directive:

```
g++ -DPRODUCT=\"HFTLibrary.h\"
```

I can set this in the "Command" field of the Project Properties and works fine.

But I cannot set it as a Symbol:
Name=PRODUCT
Value=\"HFTLibrary.h\"

The final " character is deleted after I press OK

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Right click on your project and open the property dialog (or Alt+Enter)
2. Go to `C/C++ Build->Settings`
3. Activate `Tool settings` and look up your compiler (i.e. GCC C++ Compiler)
4. Click on `Preprocessor`
5. Click on `Add` and enter your symbol

...  hmmmm... After testing this with my eclipse version `Version: Mars Release (4.5.0) Build id: 20150621-1200` it seems there is a bug. It works for normal defines, but not when you try to define a string this way. If you don't put the quotes, then the define is added, but of course can not be used as a string in your code, and if you put the quotes it simply wraps the whole `-D...` in quotes which is wrong.

Anyway, setting it in the `Path and Symbol` property will not affect your Build, because this is only to tell where eclilpse can find includes and symbols for the indexer. For the build to be affected you must change it in the way as I described above.

Comment: Filed a bug report to eclipse https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=480855

Comment: Thank you @Devolus for indicate to use Preprocessor section. I was able to define my string this way. I am using `Eclipse CDT Kepler-SR2`

Comment: So it seems that in your version that bug doesn't exist.